# Unable to Access last end value in a range of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to access large range value as this higher end value will be change sometimes as I couldnt able to print last value, If I give lower range it is getting printed but when I give higher range like 73138176 or more than 7 digits it is getting memory error,as I am using `Python 2.7.10`, can anyone help me to get print the value of last range in this version of Python

```
lbas_on_bank = []
start=0
end=73138176
for lba in range(start,end):
    if len(lbas_on_bank)>50:
        lbas_on_bank = []
    else:
        lbas_on_bank.append(lba)
last_written_lba = lbas_on_bank[-1]
print(last_written_lba)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: Why not simple `print (end-1)` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner . In my entire code end value is keeps changing, So whatever you give end value it should work ,I have tried using range and xrange but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `xrange()` instead of `range()`

Or

```
try:
  your code..
except MemoryError as er:
  print(er)
```

Comment: ... because `range` in Python 2 builds an entire list first, whereas `xrange` does not.

Comment: I dont want exception to arise instead I need to print or access higher range of last value